# How to $\text {find the maximum value of}$ $x^2 +xy$?

Tags: real-analysis

How   to   $\text {find the maximum value of}$ $x^2 +xy$ subject to the condition $x^2 +y^2 \le 1$

My attempt :$$x^2+y^2=(3-2\sqrt{2})x^2+(2\sqrt{2}-2)x^2+y^2 $$

Now  by A.M and G.M  inequality we have

$$(3-2\sqrt{2})x^2+(2\sqrt{2}-2)x^2 +y^2 \ge 2(3-2\sqrt{2})^{\frac{1}{2}}xy+(2\sqrt{2}-2)x^2 $$

after that im not  able to proceed further

Comment: Can you use Lagrange Multipliers?

Comment: @Deepak no  i don't know that method

Comment: Consider $x^2+xy$ as a function of two variables, i.e. $f(x,y) = x^2+xy$, and consider your condition as $\varphi (x,y) \le 0$, i.e. $\varphi (x,y) = x^2+y^2-1$. Now, form so called Langrange function $F(x,y,\lambda) = f(x,y) + \lambda \varphi(x,y)$. Finally, The search for the conditional extremum of function $f$ is reduced to the search for the ordinary extremum of the so-called. Lagrange functions $F$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the maximum directly:

- $x=r\cos t, y=r\sin t$ with $t\in [0,2\pi]$ and $r\in [0,1]$

Hence,
$$x^2+xy=r^2(\cos^2 t + \sin t\cos t)= \frac{r^2}{2}(1+\cos 2t + \sin 2t)$$
$$=\frac{r^2}{2}\left(1+\frac{2}{\sqrt 2}\sin \left(2t+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right)$$
$$\leq \frac 12\left(1+\frac{2}{\sqrt 2}\right) =\frac{1+\sqrt 2}{2}$$

Equality is reached for $r=1$ and $t= \frac{\pi}{8}$.

Answer (score 2):

You have: $x^2 + xy \le x^2 + x\sqrt{1- x^2} = f(x)$ . The next step is to find the maximum of $f(x)$ and I leave it for you to take care...

Comment: thanks u @Deepsea  is maximum $\frac{1 + \sqrt 2}{2}$ ?

Comment: oksss@ Deep sea see $$(3-2\sqrt{2})x^2+(2\sqrt{2}-2)x^2 +y^2 \ge 2(3-2\sqrt{2})^{\frac{1}{2}}xy+(2\sqrt{2}-2)x^2 $$


$$(3-2\sqrt{2})x^2+ y^2 \ge 2(3-2\sqrt{2})^{\frac{1}{2}}xy $$

$$x^2+ y^2 \ge 2(3-2\sqrt{2})^{\frac{1}{2}}xy $$

$$1\ge 2(3-2\sqrt{2})^{\frac{1}{2}}xy =2( \sqrt 2-1)xy  $$

$$1 \ge2( \sqrt 2-1)xy  $$

$$\frac{1}{2( \sqrt 2-1)} \ge xy  $$


$$\frac{( \sqrt 2+1)}{2} \ge xy  $$

Comment: oks@Deep sea  i mean  it is upperbound